# Optimising the double for-loop to find the count of particular value on 2-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop

To calculate the `number of blank spaces` on board, I need to call the following piece of code every time.

```
for i in range(game.width):
        for j in range(game.height):
            if game.__board_state__[i][j] == 0:
                blank_spaces += 1
```

Currently `game.width = 7` and `game.height = 7`. So there is a loop with the complexity of `O(width*height)`. Is there a builtin function/ or any other way, that is more optimized?

Comment: `O(width * height)`, and that's really not so bad for n = 7.

Comment: No, there is nothing more optimized. Every algorithm will have to look at each cell at least once, and thus have the same time complexity as yours.

Comment: if you use a numpy array as your boardstate, you can vectorise

Comment: I think the other comments and the answer by COLDSPEED already hit it. Just a minor addition: *If* your board dimension is big and you need that count often, you may add a blank_space counter as member to the board and update it on every access to the board fields. Wether that is helps depends on the ratio of width * height * calls to count vs. calls to change a board field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a builtin function/ or any other way, that is more optimized?

I don't think so, but there's no harm in trying out some alternatives.

```
board = np.random.choice(3, (1000, 1000)).tolist()
```

**Option 1**
*Nested loops*

```
%%timeit
c = 0
for i in board:
    for j in i:
        if j == 0:
            c += 1

10 loops, best of 3: 60.4 ms per loop
```

Commit this number to memory. This serves as our benchmark for comparison.

Next, let's try and "optimise" by getting rid of the `if` check. This turns out to be counterproductive, making things worse.

```
%%timeit
c = 0
for i in board:
    for j in i:
        c += (j == 0)

10 loops, best of 3: 99.3 ms per loop
```

**Option 2**
*List comprehension*

```
%timeit sum(1 for i in board for j in i if j == 0)
10 loops, best of 3: 62.3 ms per loop
```

Doesn't seem to be faster. You can, however, build a list (faster and lighter than a generator, but more memory consuming), which actually seems to improve things for *huge* data (it's still not worth it on smaller matrices) -

```
%timeit sum([1 for i in board for j in i if j == 0])
10 loops, best of 3: 58.5 ms per loop
```

**Option 3**
*Vectorisation*

```
%timeit np.equal(board, 0).sum()
10 loops, best of 3: 74.8 ms per loop

%timeit (np.array(board) == 0).sum()
10 loops, best of 3: 77.3 ms per loop
```

No bueno.

In the end, your nested loop is the "fastest" in terms of constants associated with the Big-Oh. In terms of algorithmic complexity, these options are *all the same*.